# All pods files are not installed using 'pod install'

Tags: cocoapods, podfile, pod-install

I'm basically pod installing using terminal, but not all my pod files are installed, some of them remain 'Red' as below.

What should I do about this?

[image]

Here is my podfile as well:

[image]

Comment: Are you seeing any errors when running pod install?

Comment: nopes no error at all

Answer (score 1):

- Close Xcode
- `pod deintegrate`
- `pod install`
- Open Xcode

Answer (score 0):

The issue was happening because iCloud was trying to sync the folders with cloud. Turning off iCloud Desktop & Document Folders sync then *pod deintegrate &
pod install* solved my problem.

**Turning off iCloud sync from System Preferences:**

[image]